# __shared__ variable behaving oddly CUDA

Tags: cuda

Consider the Below code Which runs under **9us** on **K20** :

```
__global__ void histogram( unsigned char *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{

    __shared__ unsigned char localDispersedHistogram[ 256  ] [ 32 ];
    __shared__ unsigned int partHist[ 256 ] ;

    int i ;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int pixelOffset = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) +  threadIdx.x;
    uint8_t val = inputPointer[ pixelOffset ];

    uint8_t  data = val/ 8 ;
    uint8_t  position = val % 8 ;

    /**Trying to avoid loops thats why this code */
    localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  tx % 32 ] = 0 ;

    __syncthreads();

    TURN_ON( localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  data ] , position );

     __syncthreads();

    partHist[ tx ] = 0;

    int k = 0 ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) {
        k++;
    }

}
```

Now the below code take **72us** on access of shared Variable:

```
__global__ void histogram( unsigned char *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{

    __shared__ unsigned char localDispersedHistogram[ 256  ] [ 32 ];
    __shared__ unsigned int partHist[ 256 ] ;

    int i ;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int pixelOffset = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) +  threadIdx.x;
    uint8_t val = inputPointer[ pixelOffset ];

    uint8_t  data = val/ 8 ;
    uint8_t  position = val % 8 ;

    /**Trying to avoid loops thats why this code */
    localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  tx % 32 ] = 0 ;

    __syncthreads();

    TURN_ON( localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  data ] , position );

     __syncthreads();

    partHist[ tx ] = 0;




    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) {
        partHist[ tx ]++;
    }

}
```

Why should the shared access make such a huge difference?
I understand shared access is expensive than register access but if you look in the above code, the line

```
TURN_ON( localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  data ] , position );
```

is also using shared variable, how come the manipulation of localDispersedHistogram takes less time , only the partHist access is taking crazy time ?

Help.

Update: 
My Apologies:

My kernel configuration is <<< 256 , 256 >>>

FULL Code:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <conio.h>


#define SIZE_OF_OUTPUT_ARRAY 256 * 256 * 256
#define SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY 256 * 256 

#define TURN_ON(DATA,POSITION) (DATA|=(1<<(POSITION)))


__global__ void histogram( unsigned char *inputPointer, int *outputPointer)
{
    #if 1   
    __shared__ unsigned char localDispersedHistogram[ 256  ] [ 32 ];
    __shared__ long long partHist[ 256 ] ;

    int i ;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int pixelOffset = (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) +  threadIdx.x;
    uint8_t val = inputPointer[ pixelOffset ];

    uint8_t  data = val/ 8 ;
    uint8_t  position = val % 8 ;


    for ( int j =  0 ; j < 32 ; j++) {
        localDispersedHistogram[ tx ] [ j ] = 0;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    TURN_ON( localDispersedHistogram [  tx ] [  data ] , position );

     __syncthreads();

    //partHist[ tx ] = 0;

    int sum = 0 ;


    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) {
        sum += (localDispersedHistogram [  i ] [  tx/ 8 ] & ( 1 << (tx % 8 ))) >> (tx % 8 ) ;
    }
    partHist[ tx ] = sum;

    atomicAdd( &outputPointer[ tx ] , partHist[ tx ]  );

    #endif

}



int main()
{

    #if 1
    printf(" Code Name, Sad buddy 17 ");

    unsigned char *inputPointer = (unsigned char * ) malloc (SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY);

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY ; i ++ ) {

        int t = rand() % 256 ; 
        //int t = 0; 
        inputPointer [ i ]   = t;

    }

    unsigned char *device_inputPointer;
    int  *device_outputPointer;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_inputPointer, SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY);
    cudaMemcpy( device_inputPointer,  inputPointer , SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMalloc((void**)&device_outputPointer, 256 * sizeof ( int ) );
    cudaMemset(device_outputPointer,0,256 * sizeof ( int ) );

    histogram <<< 256 , 256 >>>  ( device_inputPointer , device_outputPointer  );


    unsigned int *output = ( unsigned int * )malloc ( 256 * sizeof( int ));

    cudaMemcpy( output,  device_outputPointer , 256 * sizeof( int ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );





    unsigned int CPUHist [ 256 ]  ;
    unsigned int GPUHist [ 256 ]  ;

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ;i ++ ) {
        CPUHist[ i ] = 0;
        GPUHist [ i ] = 0;

        //printf( " %d " ,  inputPointer[ i ]);
    }


    for ( int i = 0 ; i < SIZE_OF_INPUT_ARRAY ; i++ ) {
        CPUHist[ inputPointer [ i ] ] ++;
    }





    int flag = 0 ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ;i ++ ) {
        printf(" %d  GPUHist  %d CPUHist\n" , output[ i ] , CPUHist[i]);

        if (output[ i ] != CPUHist[i]  ) {
            flag = 1 ;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n======================\n\n");

    if ( flag ) {
        printf("TEST CASE FAIL ");
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST CASE Pass");
    }

    printf("\n\n======================\n\n");


    cudaDeviceReset();

    #endif
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How dou you set up your thread blocks? Maybe it's a issue with bank conflicts?

Comment: Are you reading timings only once or do you repeat the same bench several times and take average?

Comment: What is "TURN_ON", and what does it do?

Comment: Niether of these codes is writing to global state (i.e. `outputPointer` - that is, unless `TURN_ON` is a macro with `outputPointer` hard coded in it), therefore you are almost certainly dealing with variations in compiler optimization.  Since you haven't provided a code anybody else could actually test for you, this is just speculation, but there are many examples of questions just like this on SO.  Fix your code by making it do something that is actually inspected by the host program, and you will get different results.  Voting to close as you have not provided a complete, useful code.

Comment: The complete Code added

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't actually posted *both complete cases* for comparison, I'm inferring your two cases based on your first posting and your update.

When you have code like this:

```
int sum = 0 ;



int k = 0 ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) {
    k++;
}

partHist[ tx ] = sum;

atomicAdd( &outputPointer[ tx ] , partHist[ tx ]  );
```

(or even if your `k` variable is replaced by `sum`, it does not matter) the compiler can figure out what will always end up in `partHist[tx]` *without* actually running any of the previous code.  Therefore it can optimize the previous code out (i.e. delete it) and still get the same result, and it will do so.  The code execution is therefore very much shorter, and you are getting the ~9us timing result.

On the other hand, when your code is as posted:

```
int sum = 0 ;


for ( int i = 0 ; i < 256 ; i ++ ) {
    sum += (localDispersedHistogram [  i ] [  tx/ 8 ] & ( 1 << (tx % 8 ))) >> (tx % 8 ) ;
}
partHist[ tx ] = sum;

atomicAdd( &outputPointer[ tx ] , partHist[ tx ]  );
```

Then this code depends on the preceding code to determine the result, and the compiler cannot optimize it out.

You can get additional confirmation of this perhaps by compiling with no optimization (`nvcc -G ...`) or else using `cuobjdump -sass mycode` to dump out the generated assembly code in each case, and you will discover a major difference in the kernel code at the assembly level, due to compiler optimization.

Whenever relative small changes are made to a code, and huge changes in execution timing occur, we should always suspect a compiler optimization side-effect.